# How to get an OnPreferenceChanged event from a SeekBarPreference using androidx

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have been trying to make an android settings screen, with a few SeekBarPreferences, to choose three numbers from 0 to 10.
However, my OnPreferenceChanged code does not get called.
My settings activity code:

```java
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.preference.Preference;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;
import androidx.preference.SeekBarPreference;

public class AdvancedSettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.settings, new AdvancedSettingsFragment())
                .commit();
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    public static class AdvancedSettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.advanced_preferences, rootKey);
            final SharedPreferences prefs=getContext().getSharedPreferences("gameSettings",0);
            final SharedPreferences.Editor prefsedit=prefs.edit();
            SeekBarPreference red=findPreference("redseekbar");
            SeekBarPreference green=findPreference("greenseekbar");
            SeekBarPreference blue=findPreference("blueseekbar");
            red.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                    prefsedit.putInt("red",(int)newValue);
                    prefsedit.apply();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),newValue+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    return true;
                }
            });
            green.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                    prefsedit.putInt("green",(int)newValue);
                    prefsedit.apply();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),newValue+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    return true;
                }
            });
            blue.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                    prefsedit.putInt("blue",(int)newValue);
                    prefsedit.apply();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),newValue+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

My preference layout code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <SeekBarPreference
        app:key="redseekbar"
        app:title="Red"
        app:summary="The red change value"
        android:max="10"
        app:defaultValue="0"
        app:showSeekBarValue="true"/>
    <SeekBarPreference
        app:key="greenseekbar"
        app:title="Green"
        app:summary="The green change value"
        android:max="10"
        app:defaultValue="0"
        app:showSeekBarValue="true"/>
    <SeekBarPreference
        app:key="blueseekbar"
        app:title="Blue"
        app:summary="The blue change value"
        android:max="10"
        app:defaultValue="0"
        app:showSeekBarValue="true"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

How should I go about getting an onpreferencechanged-like event from a seekbarpreference?
(I am using v7 support libraries, and switching/adding new ones is not an option)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I accidentally forgot to call .show() on my Toasts. Also, I had improperly configured it for testing.